# Extracting date in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a column due date in the format 20210701 (YYYYMMDD), using SQL I want to extract all the dates apart from 5th of particular month ( As highlighted in the pic below )

[image]

I used the below code:

```
SELECT Due_Date_Key
FROM Table
WHERE Due_Date_Key <>20210705
```

However the error in the above code is it will exclude only the month of jul but not for other months.
How can extract the dates apart from 5th from the entire column.

Help would be much appreciated.

Note that column DUE_DATE_KEY is numeric.

Comment: you could propably use NOT IN instead of <>

Comment: @Abra the column is numeric

Comment: @MarEll I think that would still filter for the month we input right? eg ` SELECT Due_Date_Key
FROM Table
WHERE Due_Date_Key NOT IN 20210705` PLease correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Abra. Would it be possible to extract the last two digits and then filtering the number apart from 05, Would the below code work ? ``` SELECT *, RIGHT (due_date_key,2) AS Day FROM table WHERE day <> 05```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more SQLish way would be to convert string to date and then check if day is not 5

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
WHERE DATE_PART('day', to_date(cast(DUE_DATE_KEY as varchar), 'YYYYMMDD')) != 5
```

Comment: Hi @SagarPanchal I tried the above code, however I'm getting the following error -- " No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."--. Not sure how to go about the same, any inputs will help!!

Comment: I tried the below code, ``` select *,  RIGHT(due_date_key,2) AS Day
FROM T WHERE Day > 5``` I'm getting an error " No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts." Not sure how to go about from here

Comment: @Sid Which Postgres version are you using? RIGHT function is available after v9.3. Also, why are you doing day > 5, that syntactically wrong because you don't have "Day" as a column and even if you've, you'll miss all the days before 5th

you can use following SQL to get the day as a separate column
```
SELECT Table.*, DATE_PART('day', to_date(DUE_DATE_KEY, 'YYYYMMDD')) FROM Table WHERE DATE_PART('day', to_date(DUE_DATE_KEY, 'YYYYMMDD')) != 5

```

Comment: thank you for the inputs, yes I wanted to bring dates other than 5th. I tried the above code. I'm getting an error, I have created a dummy table and ran the query suggested. Please find the link for the error thrown. [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=50de77a19878c5d8bc88653700648368)

Comment: @Sid You're seeing error because DUE_DATE_KEY was int(8). It needs to be converted to string.
Check this updated [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2aee417db29cd13268e8fc304e83447c)

Comment: Thank u Sagar Panchal, discussion was very insightful.

Answer (score 2):

Using [modulo](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html) operator to determine whether the last two digits of DUE_DATE_KEY are 05.

```
select * from T where DUE_DATE_KEY % 100 <> 5
```

Using your sample data, the above query returns the following:

```
due_date_key
20210701
20210708
20210903
```

Refer to this [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=25a3c36156df28f6773b4f732e41792d)